# In OAuth2 why is it authorization code and not authentication code?

Tags: oauth-2.0

From section [1.3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.1):

> The authorization code provides a few important security benefits,
> such as the ability to *authenticate* the client, as well as the
> transmission of the access token directly to the client without
> passing it through the resource owner's user-agent and potentially
> exposing it to others, including the resource owner.

Since *authorization code* allows for *authenticating* the client (as an additional security measure), why isn't it called *authentication code*?

Answer (score 0):

It is primarily called authorization code because OAuth 2.0 is about authorization and not about (user) authentication.

It doesn't actually authenticate the client in the traditional "static" or "pre-established" sense. It just makes sure that the client requesting the token is the same as the that the authorization response was sent to.

In fact there's a separate set of client authentication options that can be applied to actually authenticate the client to the token endpoint in the classic sense.

Comment: For some reason, I'm missing the final piece to get to the Eureka! moment. I just can't understand why it is not considered authentication. When the client/application obtains the token, the user HAD TO AUTHENTICATE otherwise it would not get it. Therefore, a client/app having the token is indeed correlated with an authentication process -- that is wherein my confusion lies. Why it is considered only an authorization framework, when clearly the user has to authenticate itself?

Comment: how the user authenticates is out of scope of OAuth 2.0; the code does not represent the act of authentication but the act of access delegation (i.e. allowing the client to get an access token), so the user really authorizes the client to act on his behalf via the code